# Beamer Bibliography Text Margin

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, pdftex, margins

To make reference in beamer bibliography, I used the following commands

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
```

Then I created a frame that allows frame break using

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
```

And started bibliography with usual \begin{bibliography} command.

The references are coming is text-style (e.g. [ABC14] etc) but the margin of the description of [ABC14] is not restricted to right side of [ABC14] as mentioned in following Beamer Pic.
[image: Beamer Pic]

I want it to be like usual latex, as shown in following Latex Pic.[image]

Can anyone please help me out? If [amsalpha] style referencing is possible without this kind of margin issue, it will be helpful.

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{11.2}{7.2}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\cite{HVE-A} did this. \cite{HVE-B} did something else.
\pagebreak

\section{References}
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
    \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \begin{thebibliography}{}
            \frametitle{References}
            \Fontvi
            \bibitem[BW07]{HVE-A} Dan Boneh and Brent Waters, ``Conjunctive, subset, and range queries on encrypted data''.
            \bibitem[IP08]{HVE-B} Vincenzo Iovino and Giuseppe Persiano, ``Hidden-vector encryption with groups of prime order''.
        \end{thebibliography}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: How to upload the text file? Can I paste the code here?

Comment: yes, just add the code and use the markup button `{}` above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt, define \bibindent to 2em (adjustable) as such

```
  \def\bibindent{2em}
  \begin{thebibliography}{99 \bibindent}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{11.2}{7.2}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\cite{HVE-A} did this. \cite{HVE-B} did something else.
\pagebreak

\section{References}
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
    \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \def\bibindent{2em}
        \begin{thebibliography}{99 \bibindent}
            \frametitle{References}
            \Fontvi
            \bibitem[BW07]{HVE-A} Dan Boneh and Brent Waters, ``Conjunctive, subset, and range queries on encrypted data''.
            \bibitem[IP08]{HVE-B}Vincenzo Iovino and Giuseppe Persiano, ``Hidden-vector encryption with groups of prime order''.
    \end{thebibliography}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```